# Custom Woocommerce checkout filed yields a Json error when validating

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I created a couple of custom required checkboxes to the WooCommerce checkout.  Everything was working as it should but it suddenly started displaying the following error.
**SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 4**

I'm using the following code to create the fields:

```
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_after_terms_and_conditions', 'my_custom_checkout_field');

function my_custom_checkout_field( $checkout ) {

woocommerce_form_field( 
    'delivery', array(
    'type'          => 'checkbox',
    'class'         => array('input-checkbox'),
    'label'         => __('Location outside major city areas may require additional business days for delivery.'),
    'required'  => true,
    )

);

woocommerce_form_field( 
    'customer', array(
    'type'          => 'checkbox',
    'class'         => array('input-checkbox'),
    'label'         => __('If the customer provides a work or home address of others instead of her/his own address, the Company will NOT be responsible if any problem occurs when delivering the goods.'),
    'required'  => true,
    )

);}
```

The following code is used to process the new checkout fields:

```
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_process', 'my_custom_checkout_field_process');

  function my_custom_checkout_field_process() {

if (!$_POST['delivery']){
    wc_add_notice( sprintf(__('You must accept Additional Shipping Conditions.', 'themename')) ,'error'  );
}    
if (!$_POST['customer']){
    wc_add_notice( sprintf(__('You must accept responsibility for address misplacement.', 'themename')) ,'error'  );
}
}
```

It must have something to do with $_POST because if I remove the if statements then it will display the normal error message and not the JSON error.

Any ideas would be great.

Comment: use the network monitor to look if the AJAX response is correct, e.g. with firefox : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Network_Monitor

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  I checked it out and got the following -         Notice:  Undefined index: delivery in /woocommerce-functions.php on line 466. Is the key named delivery not posting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out.  What fixed it was I needed to use isset in the conditional.

old code:

```
if (!$_POST['delivery']){
    wc_add_notice( sprintf(__('You must accept Additional Shipping Conditions.', 'themename')) ,'error'  );
} 

if (!$_POST['customer']){
    wc_add_notice( sprintf(__('You must accept responsibility for address misplacement.', 'themename')) ,'error'  );
}
```

Correct code using isset:

```
if (!isset($_POST['delivery'])){
    wc_add_notice( sprintf(__('You must accept Additional Shipping Conditions.', 'themename')) ,'error'  );
} 

if (!isset($_POST['customer'])){
    wc_add_notice( sprintf(__('You must accept responsibility for address misplacement.', 'themename')) ,'error'  );
}
```